# Google apps spreadsheet parents folder ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-drive-api

I have a google spreadsheet that is keeping track of the files and their names that are inside the folder where the spreadsheet is.
I have looked and can not find how to get the location or ID of that sheet
In MS CMD script it would be "%~dp0".
How to do this in google apps spreadsheet script.

```
 function FnctnMenuUpdateGetLocation() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SSID=ss.get.getId();
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(SSID);

  Browser.msgBox(SSID);
  Browser.msgBox(add);
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmsQN3N9km70dGwtLTJXVVBzbmJhdmE5OFpkbTVxelE&usp=sharing
ya, I am working in it
this is a live sheet

From what I have how do you get the address of the spreadsheet in google drive
from the spread sheet I will be having it add folder/dir and file that I need

since google docs is not google drive how is the interface from Spreadsheet to the google drive

Comment: How is the code you quoted failing?

Comment: I do not have the address of the sheet in the google drive.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking- you already have the ID of the spreadsheet in the SSID variable. If you need the URL, you can use `getUrl()`

Comment: I looking for its address in Google DRIVE so the GOOGLE Drive API So I can add folder/directory and file to the my Google drive
or rename existing file folder or move file and folder
this use to be in Google docs but what I had in note from before DID not work

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Perhaps you would have better luck with the DriveApp service rather than the DocsList service.  This  is a newer service which contains the old DocsList functions and more.  It may help you bridge the individual file and the Drive interaction you are looking for. A little clarity on what you are trying to do may help us propose a better solution.

Comment: DriveApp service what is its TAG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the Document Service and Drive Service can report which folder(s) a spreadsheet is in.

Here's your function, updated to show the name of a folder that contains the spreadsheet, using both services.

[image]

```
function FnctnMenuUpdateGetLocation() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var SSID=ss.getId();

   var fileInDocs = DocsList.getFileById(SSID);
   var folderInDocs = fileInDocs.getParents()[0].getName();

   var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(SSID);
   var folderinDrive = fileInDrive.getParents().next().getName();

   Browser.msgBox("Docs says: " + folderInDocs +
                  ", Drive says: " + folderinDrive);
}
```

Document Service's `.getParents()` method returns an array of folder objects, while Drive's returns an iterator, so the details of how to retrieve a specific parent folder(s) once you've got all of them differs.

Note that a spreadsheet may be "contained" in multiple folders... in this case, we've assumed that the first folder in the list is the only one - that assumption may be invalid.

Comment: `DocsList` appears deprecated (undefined) now.  This script no longer runs as is.

Comment: Also using `DriveApp.getFolderById()` to get the file is weirder (even if it works) than `getFileById` as suggested by the other answer here.

Answer (score 7):

## This works as of June 2018

This answer also assumes that you are only interested in the first folder in the list of parents.

```
var spreadsheetId =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var spreadsheetFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
var folderId = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();
```

Comment: it requires Drive permission, I have another question if you can help. suppose if we want to publish the script as add-on, can we do it in such a way that users don't have to give permission to author of this script?

Comment: This doesn't generate an error, but it doesn't return parents for me, either.  Does it only work if you are the owner of the spreadsheet?

Comment: @JanineWhite Sorry, I don't know about how Google Sheets permissions work. If I had to guess, you probably must be the owner of the spreadsheet to see the parent folder.

Comment: @WalterStabosz I tested a bit more. You don't have to be the owner of the spreadsheet, but you do need to have permission to view or better on the folder to get the folder information. For example, if someone shares a spreadsheet with you, but not the folder it's in, you can't get the folder properties, unfortunately.