# How to get the ID of the apps script inside a spreadsheet

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-play-services

My program works like this:

1 - Make a copy of a public google spreadsheet to my drive account (the account of the user in the device), with the Drive Api, that works fine

2 - the public google spreadsheet has a apps script inside with a simple function, i need to execute that function.

3 - the function in the apps script is executed excelent (with the ID of the script), with the Apps script api from android.

the problem is: each time is performed the copy of the spreadsheet, the script inside changes the ID, i need a way to get that ID always.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: my program works fine, only i need the way of list the apps scripts ID from the drive account.

Comment: Check this related questions which might help you with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582161/google-apps-spreadsheet-parents-folder-id and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51903/google-apps-script-trying-to-get-the-id-of-a-file-outputs-an-error.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem copying a spreadsheet with an apps script inside - and the script ID changes once copied,

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an old post, hopefully this is useful for anyone looking:

```
var scriptID = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
```

Source: [Google Apps Script Services API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getscriptid)

Comment: I think you can't use directly in the problem described above because this would be running within the old script which wouldn't give you the ID of the new script.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer.
If the code you suggested lives in the newly created sheet, then seba would need to already know the script ID in order to get this line of code to run.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by doing the following;

IN THE SHEET THAT IS BEING COPIED

1. add a function to the sheet's script with the following code: `function ScriptID(){return ScriptApp.getScriptId()}`
2. In some cell add the formula `=ScriptID()`
3. access the value of that cell to retrieve the script ID.

Now, when you copy the original, the function and the formula will be copied with it. In the new sheet, the result of the formula will show the script id for that sheet

WARNING: This may present some security issues since now your sheet's script ID is exposed to anyone with read access to your sheet.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you can alleviate the security concern by putting the cell in hidden and protected sheet

Answer (score 1):

As of the date of this post, there is no built-in, programmatic way to get the ID of the Apps Script project file bound to a Sheets file.

If that changes in the future, please comment below to let me know.
An existing feature request to add this capability is at the link below.  Please click the star in the upper left hand corner.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037

In reference to the answer about getting the ID by putting a function in a Sheets cell, putting a function in a Sheets cell that calls a function name in a "gs" file requires that you open the bound script file and enter the function.  So, if you are going to do that, you could just manually get the Apps Script project file ID.

There is also no way to use the Drive API to list Apps Script project files that are bound to a document.  The Drive API won't find an Apps Script files that are not shown in Drive.

The Google Drive API won't find Apps Script files that are not visibly shown in your Google Drive.  So, the Drive API can't be used to get any information either.  And the Apps Script API won't list all Apps Script files in your account.  It will only get files by ID.  So, you can only get one Apps Script file and you need to know the file ID.

Comment: If the function is present in the gs file when the public spreadsheet copied, then the gs file, along with the function, gets copied as well.

If saba can put the custom function into the gs file of the public spreadsheet and the formula into a cell inside the public spreadsheet, then when his program copies the public spreadsheet it can use the File ID that is returned to access the values in the cell and, therefore the Script ID