# Find the folder ID of the current Google Apps spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

In a script bound to a Google Sheet, how can I learn the ID (not the name) of the folder containing the current sheet? I want to do this:

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B9momRZYw4DVTlJVeXNpX25BemM').getFiles();

but using a variable that represents the folder ID, like this:

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

The problem is I cannot figure out how to obtain the parent folder's ID. I realize the current sheet may reside in several different folders (mine doesn't), but surely there is some way to get the ID of the folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is quite straightforward using [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents()) `getParents()` method.
Code goes like this :

```
function getParentFolder(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  var folders = file.getParents();
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    Logger.log('folder name = '+folders.next().getName());
  }
}
```

Use `folders.next().getId()` to get the folder(s) ID(s).

[image]

Comment: Note that this is almost a duplicate of this other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582161/google-apps-spreadsheet-parents-folder-id?rq=1) but I answer it to show an updated version of Mogsdad's code that was using a (now) deprecated service.

Comment: folders.next().getId() was the piece of the puzzle I was missing. Thanks for that, and for revising Mogsdad's code to the "new" service.